# SQL Server 2012 query blocked with LCK_M_IS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm struggling to understand how the following two queries could be blocking each other.

Running query (could be almost anything though):
insert bulk [Import].[WorkTable] ...

I'm trying to run the following SELECT query at the same time:

```
SELECT *
FROM    ( SELECT * FROM @indexPart ip
JOIN    sys.indexes i (NOLOCK)
    ON  i.object_id = ip.ObjectId
    and i.name = ip.IndexName) i
CROSS
APPLY   sys.dm_db_index_physical_Stats(db_id(), i.object_id,i.index_id,NULL,'LIMITED')  ps
WHERE   i.is_disabled = 0
```

The second query is blocked by the first query and shows a LCK_M_IS as wait info. Import information is that the temporary table @indexPart contains one record of an index on a completely different table. My expectation is that the cross apply tries to run the stats on that one index which has nothing to do with the other query running.

Thanks

**EDIT (NEW):**

After several more tests I think I found the culprit but again can't explain it.

1. Bulk Insert Session has an X lock on table [Import].[WorkTable]
2. The query above is checking for an Index on table [Import].[AnyOtherTable] BUT is requesting an IS lock on [Import].[WorkTable]. I've verified again and again that the query above (when running the stuff without cross apply) is only returning an index on table [Import].[AnyOtherTable].
3. Now here comes the magic, changing the CROSS APPLY to an OUTER APPLY runs through just fine without any locking issues.

I hope someone can explain this to me ...

Comment: Could be blocking on metadata tables. Look at the list of all locks held by the two statements at the time of blocking.

Comment: It seems the second query is requesting a SCH_S lock on two system tables (sysidxstats, syssingleobjrefs) which ends up blocking. I'm just surprised I couldn't find any mention on this on the page for sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats.

Comment: I doubt that SCH_S blocks on system tables because nothing is SCH_M them. Are you sure? Post locking information.

Comment: @usr: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7691580/deadlock-on-bulk-inserts seems to suggest that bulk inserts can take sch-m locks...

Comment: @BenThul true, but that would be a SCH-M on user tables, not system tables. This might be the true reason. I have a hunch that the OP has misinterpreted some lock information.

Comment: True. my suggestion for the OP would be to post the xml output from the blocking monitor - she tells the truth and nothing but the truth.

Comment: Thanks guys for all the input. I did some more testing and checked the output of sp_lock and added an edit to my original post!

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be at the where clause you used. It should be within the inline table. The following change could make a difference.

```
FROM    ( SELECT * FROM @indexPart ip
JOIN    sys.indexes i (NOLOCK)
ON  i.object_id = ip.ObjectId
and i.name = ip.IndexName
WHERE   i.is_disabled = 0) i
```

If you do like so, this may reduce the number of records passed onto the cross apply statement.

Comment: SQL Server pushes that predicate inwards for you.

Comment: Yep that wasn't the issue.